# Can we use Zweites Frühstück for brunch in German language?

Tags: speaking

I basically know that Frühstück, Mittagessen and Abendessen are common in Germany. However, I am interested to know how **brunch** is called in German language. Can we use **zweites Frühstück** for brunch? Or is there any specific name for it?

Comment: *Zweites Frühstück* is a *Butterbrot* you eat at the break room at work or on the schoolyard.

Comment: "Spätstück" ;) https://www.google.com/search?q=sp%C3%A4tst%C3%BCck

Answer (score 18):

Zweites Frühstück implies there has been an erstes Frühstück. Brunch is simply called Brunch. To eat brunch is called *brunchen*.

> Wollen wir Samstag brunchen?

Comment: Reference: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brunch

Answer (score 10):

"Zweites Frühstück" is usually for people who start working very early and need another meal between their early breakfast and lunch.

In school, I had breakfast at home a 6.30 am, zweites Frühstück at 10 am during the first longer break in school ("Große Pause") and lunch at 1 pm.

"Brunch" is used in German language. When I was younger, I didn't know the word brunch. My family used to call it "spätes Frühstück".

Comment: "Spätes Frühstück" is _very fitting_ indeed, because usually - in anticipation of a brunch - any otherwise earlier meals will be skipped, even if it means the first meal will start as late as 10 or 11 am.

Comment: "Spätes Frühstück" does not fit IMO; as expressed by the word, brunch includes breakfast and lunch. It is definitely more than just a Frühstück. At the same time, on weekends, I do not see anything unusual with having breakfast only at 10 or even 11 (a later lunch and/or "tea time" notwithstanding). *That* is a "spätes Frühstück".

Answer (score 6):

Brunch is a special kind of meal. It's the combination of breakfast and lunch.

If a restaurant offers a brunch, I expect a mixture of breakfast and lunch. So there would be typical breakfast food (bread rolls, butter, jam, honey,...) but also typical lunch items (warm meat, potatoes, vegetables, ...).

If a restaurant offers a second breakfast, I expect a normal breakfast. The breakfast could be smaller than a normal breakfast, because the landlord expects, that I already had a breakfast at home.

A second breakfast is normally just a repetition of a breakfast. Or it is a prepared bread and butter sandwich for a break. A bakery could advertise their pastry/cookie as a second breakfast (you can buy it and eat it immediately as a snack).

Comment: In fact the word is a portmanteau (dt. Kofferwort) from breakfast and lunch.

Comment: In all brunch offerings at restaurants I have been to (and it's quite a few), the meal was drawn out across at least 3 to 4 hours, and the food (usually on the buffet) gradually transitioned from breakfast-like food to warm lunch dishes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fitting german expression for "zweites Frühstück" would be "**Vesper**". Brunch is the Combination of Breakfast and lunch, and is used in this way in german. So no, i would say "vesper" to the second breakfast.

This is very common in manual labour jobs. They start early, around 6 in the morning, already had their breakfast, then around 9 its the "vesper", at noon its the "mittagessen"/Lunch and then they go home at 4 to have "Kaffee". And a Dinner in the evening.

The second breakfast could in some parts of germany be called "Brotzeit" (southern area).

Comment: Mind that Vesper is also a somewhat regional term, which might also refer to the afternoon "Kaffetrinken". "Zweites Frühstück", however, is understood immediately as a meal in the morning.

Comment: "Vesper" is so much regional that we in the Ruhr area don't even use it. Most of us are just vaguely aware that it is a word for "some meal during the day, called that way in some regions of germany", but anything more specific about the meaning would elude us.

Comment: So _Vesper_ is essentially the reverse of _dinner_ – interesting! _Vesper_ (in Latin) means ‘evening’, but it now refers to a morning meal, so it has moved from late to early over time; whereas _dinner_ comes from (Vulgar) Latin _disjejunare_, which means ‘breakfast’, so it has moved from early to late over time.

Comment: @HeinrichsupportsMonica: Right, *and* it may also not mean any particular meal at all, but rather indicate that it's food taken along on a trip, no matter at what time of the day you intend to consume it.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a German term for *brunch* that is immediately understood by German native speakers, albeit not used often, there is ***Gabelfrühstück***.

For a classic German *Frühstück* ‘breakfast’, you either need just a *Messer* ‘knife’ (bread or toast) or just a *Löffel* ‘spoon’ (porridge, cereals, yogurt, …), so adding a *Gabel* ‘fork’ to the cutlery makes breakfast more like lunch.

Comment: I would not have understood this.

Comment: "that is immediately understood by German native speakers" - never heard this, and I would have no idea what is meant. I would have *guessed* it's a breakfast that does not only consist of bread, but also some food that you eat with a fork - e.g. like what is often offered in hotels for breakfast, with items like scrambled egg or (boiled) sausages.

Comment: Additionally to the two comments above by Carsten and O.R.Mapper: I don't see how "Gabel" implies brunch as one can have very well scrambled eggs or so along the (first) breakfast. I'd have no clue what you would want to say.

Comment: I heard that term *Gabelfrühstück* before. Exactly once, from hotel staff.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That’s exactly what brunch is, no? Correctly guessing the intended meaning is what I meant by “is immediately understood”.

Comment: @Crissov: Absolutely not, I'd say it's quite a different concept. I can have a breakfast that includes sausages and scrambled egg between 7 and 7:30 am. This is what I might intuitively call "Gabelfrühstück". Later on the same day, I'd still have lunch as an entirely separate and unrelated meal. Brunch, in contrast, *includes and replaces* both breakfast and lunch. If you have brunch, you do not have a separate breakfast or a separate lunch at another time. Brunch itself includes all the dishes for both breakfast and lunch, and also covers basically the morning till noon.

Comment: Sausages and scrambled eggs are known as an _English breakfast_ for a reason.